# Как организовать хранение порядка строк?

Tags: postgresql

Есть задача хранить порядок строк. 
Чтобы можно было быстро и удобно менять их местами.
И если создать столбец order с типом integer, то при изменении значения order в какой то строке,
другие значения в столбце не пересчитываются.

Например есть таблица:

```
Строка Порядок
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
```

Дальше мы меняем в строке 3 порядок на 1.
И получается

```
Строка Порядок
1        1
2        2
3        1
4        4
```

А нужно пересчитать порядок остальных строк тоже

```
Строка Порядок
1        2
2        3
3        1
4        4
```

Как правильней это организовать? Можно ли это сделать без пересчёта всех остальных значений вручную в коде и последующей записи в БД в каждую строку?

Comment: Вариантов не так и много. Кроме описанного (обновлять всё зависимое, т.е. в среднем полтаблицы), возможны ещё варианты: -
 присвоение промежуточных значений (полусумма новых соседей) с периодическим полным пересчётом; - связный список; - вырожденное (не более одного предка/потомка) дерево; - прочие варианты.